# entity framefork dbcontext multi threading

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

in a wpf application i'm using one context for the entire application and i'm trying to remove entities on a background thread but it crashes can someone explain me why and how to solve it,
 this is the code where it crashes

```
foreach (var transaction in transactions)
{
    context.Transactions.Remove(transaction);
}
```

this runs on a background thread. thanks

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: i'm not getting an error message the code just stops debugging there

Comment: likely a timeout issue, but a try/catch with some logging would be good first step to diagnosis

Comment: what do you mean a time out issue, and do you think that i can access the context from another thread and remove entities, because when i use the dispatcher of the main thread to remove it working fine

Comment: add the try/catch and find out what is going on, much surer approach than guessing

Comment: hi dbugger i try'd a try/catch and i got the error the message is This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Comment: pretty clear message -- can't do that

Comment: i can but then the ui is getting slow every time the ui thread is removing a transaction/entity when its 500 transactions/entities

Comment: entity framework is probably not the answer, or consider using multiple contexts. You can't use multiple threads with your current approach and a single thread is too slow.  Something needs to change.